# how to assign contents to elements?

Tags: javascript

I have trouble trying to assign the contents to a varible.

I have

```
 var test=document.getElementsByClassName('current')
 var title='test name';
 //doesn't show in my div element.
 test.innerHTML=title;
```

but it doesn't show in the current elements

my html

```
<div class='current'> </div>
```

Are there anyways I can try to fix this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: vanillajs is not jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an <strike>array of elements</strike> [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName). You either have to iterate that list or grab the first element (if that is the one you want to modify), and set the innerHTML of that element:

```
test[0].innerHTML = title
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable test will return an array of html DOM objects having the class name `current`
So, its your duty to specify which elements you are targeting by appending an array index to it.

```
var test=document.getElementsByClassName('current')[0] 
//return the first found DOM object with the matching class
```

Comment: It returns a NodeList, not an array. An array has all the methods in Array.prototype, but the NodeList doesn't.

Comment: right! but accessing of the target elements is done exactly the same way as how you access an array!

Comment: If you use bracket notation the access looks the same, but there are other ways to access the elements in an array. You are using the wrong terminology and will therefore not receive as many upvotes as you should. You might even get downvoted.